# How change sql query or json data?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have doctrine query:

```
SELECT b.bankId, a.status,COUNT(b.bankId) as wynik
FROM OmnisoftIntegBundle:IntClientBank a
JOIN a.bank b
WHERE a.status = 30 or a.status = 50 or a.status = 35 or a.status = 37
GROUP BY b.bankId, a.status"

$res = $query->getArrayResult();


public function getListAction() {

        $result = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('OmnisoftIntegBundle:IntClientBank')->getStat2(array('1=1'));

        return new JsonResponse(array('data' => $result, 'success' => true));

    }
```

And json encode like that:

```
{"data":[{"bankId":1,"status":30,"wynik":"776"},{"bankId":1,"status":35,"wynik":"59"},{"bankId":1,"status":50,"wynik":"150"},{"bankId":2,"status":30,"wynik":"123"},{"bankId":2,"status":35,"wynik":"28"},{"bankId":2,"status":50,"wynik":"25"},{"bankId":3,"status":30,"wynik":"229"},{"bankId":3,"status":35,"wynik":"16"},{"bankId":3,"status":37,"wynik":"1"},{"bankId":3,"status":50,"wynik":"142"},{"bankId":4,"status":30,"wynik":"342"},{"bankId":4,"status":35,"wynik":"23"},{"bankId":4,"status":37,"wynik":"1"},{"bankId":4,"status":50,"wynik":"96"},{"bankId":5,"status":30,"wynik":"72"},{"bankId":5,"status":35,"wynik":"7"},{"bankId":5,"status":50,"wynik":"10"},{"bankId":6,"status":30,"wynik":"113"},{"bankId":6,"status":35,"wynik":"3"},{"bankId":6,"status":50,"wynik":"68"},{"bankId":7,"status":30,"wynik":"17"},{"bankId":7,"status":50,"wynik":"10"},{"bankId":8,"status":30,"wynik":"13"},{"bankId":8,"status":35,"wynik":"1"},{"bankId":8,"status":50,"wynik":"6"},{"bankId":9,"status":30,"wynik":"16"},{"bankId":9,"status":35,"wynik":"2"},{"bankId":9,"status":50,"wynik":"6"},{"bankId":10,"status":30,"wynik":"4"},{"bankId":10,"status":35,"wynik":"2"},{"bankId":11,"status":30,"wynik":"2"},{"bankId":11,"status":50,"wynik":"2"},{"bankId":12,"status":30,"wynik":"4"},{"bankId":12,"status":35,"wynik":"1"},{"bankId":12,"status":50,"wynik":"1"},{"bankId":13,"status":30,"wynik":"3"},{"bankId":13,"status":50,"wynik":"2"},{"bankId":14,"status":30,"wynik":"5"},{"bankId":15,"status":30,"wynik":"1"},{"bankId":15,"status":50,"wynik":"1"},{"bankId":16,"status":30,"wynik":"1"},{"bankId":17,"status":30,"wynik":"1"},{"bankId":18,"status":30,"wynik":"2"}],"success":true}
```

I need 2 changes in json:

1) bankids mapping numbers to string (1 to first_name_bank, 2 to secound_name_bank etc...):

```
bankId: "first_name_bank"
bankId: "secound_name_bank"
```

2) change json from:

```
{"bankId":1,"status":30,"wynik":"776"}
{"bankId":1,"status":35,"wynik":"59"}
{"bankId":1,"status":50,"wynik":"150"}
```

to:

```
{"bankId":"first_name_bank","status30":"776","status35":"59","status50":"150","status37":"0"}
{"bankId":"secound_name_bank","status30":"123" ...}
...
```

How I can do that?

Comment: What have you already tried? Please add the code to your question.

Comment: I dont know how i can try it? Can i change json data or only sql query?

Comment: I try mapping banks ids to strings but CASE with ... END in doctrine doestn work :(